# Remove item after click image from ListView (Fragment, BaseAdapter)

Tags: android

I have a problem. What I can remove item after click image on ListView? Every item on list has an icon to remove.

Part of fragment:

```
ListView listView;
.....
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic_list, container, false);
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
.....
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Part of basic_list:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Part of ClassAdapter extends BaseAdapter:

```
public class ClassAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
    public ClassAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            cContext = context;
        }
....
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_adapter, null);
    .....
    holder.removeIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
        //????????????
    }
```

Part of list_adapter.xml

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/box_icon"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these code

```
 holder.removeIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

         ARRAYLIST.remove(position);///position of the getview method
         notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify to refresh


   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I haven't arraylist in adapter. List is only in Fragment.

Comment: You have passed the arraylist while calling the BaseApater class in the fragment...please check it once...

like

ClassAdapter adpter = new ClassAdapter (ARRAYLIST,getActivity());

Comment: Ravindra Kushwawa - Ok, I understand, but I can't any arraylist in the fragment. I just have ListView in fragment.

Comment: I have the array in fragment Box[] box; and I download data from internet to this array and I call in fragment adapter.setData(box); listView.setAdapter(adapter); | setData is my method in ClassAdapter: public void setData(Box[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

Comment: Use can also use Arraylist in place of yours Box[] (Array) and perform the operation like in my code..

Answer (score 1):

Below is a sample.

```
holder.removeIcon.setTag(position);//save index

holder.removeIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Integer position= (Integer) view.getTag(); //get index
        dataList.remove(position); //remove the item from data source
        notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify to refresh
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, but what is "dataList"? My listView is in Fragment, not in Adapter.

Comment: datalist means your list of items on which you set the adapter for ListView.

Comment: it's a sample. here means your data source, you should remove the item from your data source.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the clicked item from your data list which should be located in your adapter class.

You probably didnt post the entire code of your adapter class, but your adapter probably a List of the data set that is shown in your listview based on positions?

In your adapters getView method you have a parameter "position", and you can use it to remove the item at that position from your data list and then just call notifyDataSetChanged so the ListView gets updated.